# are mysql column datatypes important to maintaining efficiency?

Tags: mysql, performance, schema, types, varchar

do i need to pick the datatype of my mysql database columns carefully, or can i set things to varchar(99999) without a size limit without damaging efficency?

thanks :)

Comment: Just FYI, the maximum size for VARCHAR on MySQL is 255, so there is a size limit whether you specify one or not.

Comment: The max size of VARCHAR is up to 65535, in MySQL 5.0.3 or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undoubtedly, for non-trivial databases, datatypes are **very** important.

For mysql functionality (e.g. time, string, or aggregate functions), choosing the right datatypes is important.

For schema functionality (e.g. joining), choosing the right datatypes is important.

For performance, every byte of every field counts.

A database of all long varchars would be regrettable.

DBA's exist for a reason. :)

Answer (score 3):

Pick data types that represent the data you are storing.  If you are storing numbers, use data types designed for storing numbers.  If you are storing dates, use data types designed for storing dates.

If all of your data really is text, pick VARCHAR for columns where the length can vary, and pick CHAR for columns where the length will never vary, or where trailing spaces are not significant.  VARCHAR takes one extra byte to store the length of the field, and carries with a very small performance penalty just because the length is variable, and this creates more steps when extracting or storing data.

Note that you may want to impose size limits on the VARCHAR columns if you are using them as part of an index, since the maximum size of an index on MySQL is 1000 bytes.  So if you make all your columns VARCHAR(100), you will only be able to create composite indexes around three such fields.

(As a side note, the type VARCHAR(99999) does not exist in MySQL -- the maximum length of a VARCHAR field is 255, since only one byte is used to store the length of each VARCHAR in a record.)

Answer (score 3):

I have found that it is better to accurately declare column types when designing a new table. For example, it helps to ensure that only a number is entered into a column that should only have a number, like in a price. What would your code do if it was trying to work with a dollar amount, and it retrieved 'Asd$%*@)' because the user could enter any free form string in?

By accurately declaring the column type, you can ensure that the data that you retrieve is the same type as you are requesting, without having to do any cumbersome text parsing and error checking.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you want to do. For sorting purposes you'll want integers to be stored as integer, I'd say :)
For small databases though you probably won't suffer too much from making everything a varchar.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `select * from your_table procedure analyse(2, 5)` (adjust numbers to your convenience) to have an idea how MySQL thinks your tables should be.